# Void value expression error in return statement

Tags: ruby

Why does calling `f()` with the following definition report `void value expression` error while calling `g()` is OK?

```
def f(n)
  return n == 0 or n == 1
end

def g(n)
  return (n == 0 or n == 1)
end
```

Comment: From [the ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide): The `and` and `or` keywords are banned. The minimal added readability is just not worth the high probability of introducing subtle bugs. For boolean expressions, always use `&&` and `||` instead.

Comment: This question is a good example of why using `and` and `or` cause more problems than they're worth. Frankly, I'd rather see those key words just removed from the language. (But that will almost certainly never happen, due to backwards compatibility!)